# how to speedup python execution

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file with 4623 lines and entries in forms of string of 0s and 1s (e.g 01010111). I am comparing them character by character. I have several data sets with length of character string 100,1000 and 10,000. It takes 25 hours for 1000 and 60 hours for 10,000 to calculate. Is there any way to speed it up? I tried to use multiprocessing library, but it just duplicates values. Maybe I am using it wrong. Code:

```
f = open("/path/to/file/file.txt", 'r')
l = [s.strip('\n') for s in f]
f.close()

for a in range(0, len(l)):
    for b in range(0, len(l)):
        if (a < b):
            result = 0
            if (a == b):
                result = 1
            else:
                counter = 0
            for i in range(len(l[a])):
                if (int(l[a][i]) == int(l[b][i]) == 1):
                    counter += 1
            result = counter / 10000   
            print((a + 1), (b + 1), result)
```

I am new to python, so I think this code needs some optimization. Any help will be good. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Trying to figure out if the `if a < b:` actually implies you're looking for combinations instead of product, which those 2 nested for loops do at the moment.

Comment: Since your strings are 1's and 0's, albeit long, this sounds like a job for a bitfield and bitwise and.

Comment: Captain here: pypy or threading | *flies away*

Comment: 3 dataset files: each line entry character lengths 100, 1000 and 10,000. As for bitwise, yes it is. But to apply bitwise operations I have to convert this string to decimal and then perform. I want to perform on this kind of representation if possible.

Comment: No, don't think in decimal. Think in binary. Do a bitwise and on common length and count resulting bits that are 1. That at least seems analogous to what you do now.

Comment: Also, please provide a small sample of your data. Is it sorted by length? Your current implementation suggests so, since the length to iter over is taken from the string indexed by a.

Comment: What are you actually looking for at the end of this?   Right now the only real output is `counter`, which behaves in a somewhat strange way (originally I thought it was counting the number of matching 1 bits for each pair, but it's not) and which you don't even print out or store.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve her?

Comment: Bag of word comparison, for Natural Language Processing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The Basics

Your way of counting where both strings are 1 is extremely slow. Here's a simple example:

```
In [24]: a = '1010' * 2500

In [25]: b = '1100' * 2500

In [27]: def test1():
    counter = 0            
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if int(a[i]) == int(b[i]) == 1:
            counter += 1
    return counter

In [28]: %timeit test1()
100 loops, best of 3: 4.07 ms per loop
```

Compare that to using something that represents your strings of 1's and 0's as just bits:

```
In [29]: aba = bitarray(a)

In [30]: bba = bitarray(b)

In [31]: def test2():
   ....:     return (aba & bba).count()
   ....: 

In [32]: %timeit test2()

100000 loops, best of 3: 1.99 µs per loop
```

That is 2045 times faster. So the question is not how to speed up python, but "what data structure should I use?".

## Larger Scale

Using [bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) and a file of 10,000 lines of 100 1's and 0's, which is not your worst case, but:

```
In [22]: from bitarray import bitarray

In [23]: testdata = open('teststrs.txt')

In [24]: l = [bitarray(line.rstrip()) for line in testdata]

In [25]: len(l)
Out[25]: 10000

In [26]: len(l[0])
Out[26]: 100

In [27]: combs = combinations(l, 2)

In [28]: %time res = [(a & b[:len(a)]).count() for a, b in combs]
CPU times: user 1min 14s, sys: 396 ms, total: 1min 15s
Wall time: 1min 15s
```

or using a product, as in your example code:

```
In [30]: from itertools import product

In [31]: prod = product(l, repeat=2)

In [32]: %time res = [(a & b[:len(a)]).count() for a, b in prod]
CPU times: user 2min 51s, sys: 628 ms, total: 2min 52s
Wall time: 2min 51s
```

**Note:**

I skipped the results handling you have, since you haven't opened it up and it contains dead code:

```
if a == b:
```

will never be `True`, since in the preceding if you check that `a < b`. I take it that you have indentation or logical errors and meant something like:

```
    if a < b:
        result = 0
    elif a == b:
        result = 1
    else:
        counter = 0
        for i in range(len(l[a])):
            if (int(l[a][i]) == int(l[b][i]) == 1):
                counter += 1
        result = counter / 10000
    print((a + 1), (b + 1), result)
```

## "Real" Data

With your worst case, if I've understood it correctly:

```
In [1]: src = map(lambda i: '{:010000b}\n'.format(i), iter(lambda: random.getrandbits(10000), None))

In [2]: import random

In [3]: from itertools import islice

In [4]: with open('teststrs.txt', 'w') as datafile:
    datafile.writelines(islice(src, 0, 4623))

...

In [35]: testdata = open('teststrs.txt')

In [36]: l = [bitarray(line.rstrip()) for line in testdata]

In [37]: prod = product(l, repeat=2)

In [38]: %time res = [(a & b).count() for a, b in prod]
CPU times: user 52.1 s, sys: 424 ms, total: 52.5 s
Wall time: 52.5 s

In [39]: len(l)
Out[39]: 4623

In [40]: len(l[0])
Out[40]: 10000
```

Notice that I cheated and skipped slicing `b`. It is very **very** costly to move all that memory around, which slicing will do, as it creates new copies:

```
In [43]: %time res = [(a & b[:len(a)]).count() for a, b in prod]
CPU times: user 29min 40s, sys: 676 ms, total: 29min 41s
Wall time: 29min 40s
```

So if you know your maximum bit width in advance, or even calculate it from your data, I think it would be beneficial to pad the shorter bitarrays with zeros and then do the whole "count 1's":

```
In [18]: def test():                     
    with open('teststrs.txt') as testdata:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in testdata]
    max_len = max(map(len, lines))
    l = [bitarray(line.ljust(max_len, '0')) for line in lines]
    prod = product(l, repeat=2)
    return [(a & b).count() for a, b in prod]
   ....: 

In [19]: %timeit test()
1 loops, best of 3: 43.9 s per loop
```

Here *teststrs.txt* was composed of 4623 mixed length (random choice of 100, 1000 or 10000) strings of 1' and 0's.

Comment: Since you do `if (int(l[a][i]) == int(l[b][i]) == 1):` in your code, which actually is true where both strings contain `'1'`, I presumed that you really do want to count the 1's, although you say that you "compare them char by char". For that bitarray has an even faster function, `bitdiff`. It would require handling the different length inputs a bit differently, but would still be in the same ball park as the current answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really helpful to understand my problem.